# A advanced geometry question

Tags: euclidean-geometry

In triangle $\triangle ABC, \overline{AB}>\overline{AC}$. Mis foot of perpendicular from $C$ on external bisector of angle $\widehat{A}$. $D$ is midpoint of $\overline{BC}$ .Prove that $\overline{AB}+\overline{AC}=2\overline{DM}$.

Comment: $BA$ extended meets $CM$ extended at $E$. Triangle $CAE$ is isosceles. Show $BE = 2DM$

Answer (score 1):

I will present a slightly unusual solution to this problem...
Assume an *ellipse* with $B,C$ as foci and $A$ as a point on the ellipse.

Then what the question asks us to show is that the length $DM$ is half the length of the major axis of this *ellipse*.

For this, simply observe that the external angle bisector is actually the tangent to this ellipse at $A$.
And it is again well known that the foot of perpendicular from foci to a tangent lies on the auxilliary circle.

Hence $M$ lies on the auxilliary circle, which is exactly what was intended.